# How do I collapse UIViews programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, uikit

I'm working on my first IOS app and have run into an issue. I have a quite elaborate programmatic autoloyout UI that responds to user interaction. When a keyboard is shown certain Views must be collapsed, others moved and others spawned into existence based on a few conditions.

Now in it's default state no autolayout errors occur. But once things start moving it all comes apart. A few of the issues have to do with images retaining their height, while their view's heigconstriant is set to 0. Now I do have .scaleToFill enabled.

I have looked into stackViews however since most of my Views are of a different size with different nested UI elements stackviews do now appear to solve my issues. But I would certainly like some input on that.

Now my questions is: How do I collapse UIView and UIImageviews dynamically and programatically?

Now I don't mind typing out a lot of constraints manually, as long as it works.

Here are the constraints of the Views in question(there are more)

```
func setUpLayout() {
    // SuggestionCloud
    suggestionCloud.setConstraints(
        topAnchor: textView.bottomAnchor, topConstant: 0,
        bottomAnchor: bottomMenu.topAnchor, bottomConstant: 0,
        trailingAnchor: view.trailingAnchor, trailingConstant: -10,
        leadingAnchor: view.leadingAnchor, leadingConstant: 10)
        print("Suggestion View frame        :\(suggestionCloud.frame)")

    //WEIGHT_IMAGE_VIEW
    weigtImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    weigtImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    weigtImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    weigtImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    weigtImageView.addSubview(weightLabel);
    print("Weight Image View \(weigtImageView.frame)")

    //WEIGHT_LABEL
    weightLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weigtImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true;
    weightLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weigtImageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true;
    weightLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weigtImageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true;

    //TEXT_VIEW
    textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weigtImageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
    textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true;
    textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true;
    textView.addSubview(nameTextField)
    textView.addSubview(tagTextField)
    textView.addSubview(setButtonView)

   //TAG_CONTROLLER
    tagController.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 110).isActive = true;
    tagController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.weigtImageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
    tagController.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  self.view.leadingAnchor, constant : 10).isActive = true
    tagController.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

    //SET_BUTTON_VIEW
    setButtonView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.topAnchor).isActive = true;
    setButtonView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
    setButtonView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true;
    setButtonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 110).isActive = true;


    //NAME_TEXT_FIELD
    nameTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: setButtonView.leadingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    nameTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    nameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.topAnchor, constant: 13).isActive = true
    nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 31).isActive = true
    nameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    nameTextField.backgroundColor = .white;


    //TAG_TEXT_FIELD
    tagTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: setButtonView.leadingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    tagTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    tagTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor, constant: -13).isActive = true
    tagTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 31).isActive = true
    tagTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    tagTextField.backgroundColor = .white
```

here's the viewcontrollers setup:

```
   class UIScaleControllerVew: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, SuggenstionCloudDelegate {

let weigtImageView : UIImageView = {
    var imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "scaleVisorShadow"));
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return imageView
}()

let weightLabel : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "135 gr"
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 50.0)
    label.textAlignment = .right
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}();

let textView : UIView = {
    var view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return view;
}();
let setButtonView : UIImageView = {
    var imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "setButton"))
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return imageView;
}();



let nameTextField : UITextField = {
    var textField = UITextField();
    textField.tag = 2;
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nameFieldEditingChanged(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    return textField;
}();

let tagTextField : UITextField = {
    var textField = UITextField();
    textField.tag = 1;
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldEditingChanged(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    return textField;
}();

let bottomMenu : UIView = {
    var view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return view;
}();

let saveButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "save"), for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return button
}();

let microPhoneButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "microPhone"), for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return button;
}();

let suggestionCloud : SuggenstionCloud = {        
    let cloud =  SuggenstionCloud(image: UIImage(named: "suggestionCloud.png"))
    cloud.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return cloud;
}();
let tagController : TagController = {
    let tagController = TagController()
    tagController.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tagController;
}()

let scaleModel = ScaleModel.init()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("UIScaleController_DidLoad")
    tagTextField.delegate = self
    nameTextField.delegate = self;
    suggestionCloud.delegate = self;
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "8ED7F5")
    view.addSubview(weigtImageView)
    view.addSubview(textView)
    view.addSubview(bottomMenu);
    view.addSubview(suggestionCloud)
    view.addSubview(tagController)
    tagController.isHidden = true;


    setUpLayout()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShowNotification(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHideNotification(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

var didSetUpSuggestionCloud = false
var didSetUpTagController = false
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    guard !self.didSetUpTagController else {
        return
    }
    guard !self.didSetUpSuggestionCloud else {
        return
    }
    self.didSetUpSuggestionCloud = true
    self.didSetUpTagController = true
};
```

and here's the problematic code:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShowNotification(notification: Notification ) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        // collapse and hide bottom view
        bottomMenu.contentMode = .scaleToFill;
        bottomMenu.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true;
        bottomMenu.isHidden = true

        // collapse and hide top view
        weigtImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill;
        weigtImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true;
        weigtImageView.isHidden = true;



        // spawn my tag view
        tagController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.textView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
        tagController.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: suggestionCloud.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tagController.isHidden = false;

        // set textviews new constraints
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tagController.topAnchor).isActive = true;
        // set middleView's new constraints
        suggestionCloud.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tagController.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
        suggestionCloud.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomMenu.topAnchor, constant: -keyboardSize.height).isActive = true

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Now there are so many unexpected things happening that i'm positive that my approach to this is just wrong conceptually. 
Please let me know where I need to look for a solution.

Here are e few pictures of what is happening so far:

So when the keyboard is up: 
The weightView is collapsed: suggestioncloud and text are moved up.
If a tag is added a new view called tagController needs to be places between the texView and the suggesitonCloud. Lastyl the keybaord needs to be collapsed again.

Ill add some sscreenshots
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a strong reference to your views to be released then it is enough to execute this:

```
if view2Breleased.superview != nil {
    view2Breleased.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

The view will then disappear and be released from memory.

If you don't know what a strong reference is then for the time being, just try the code I wrote. The views will disappear anyway.

(Strong reference means you have assigned the view to a variable which survives the execution of the code `view2Breleased.removeFromSuperview()` and the exit from the function call where the code `view2Breleased.removeFromSuperview()` is.)

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by a strong reference?

Comment: Thanks for the udpate

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could look at is duplicate constraints.

Every time you call `weigtImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true` you are creating a new constraint. This does not automatically replace any previous height constraints that are active.

To replace a constraint, you need to keep a reference to it, deactivate it, and then activate a new one (and optionally assign it the the variable you use to keep a reference).

**Stack views**
Stack views could be helpful in your situation, because they automatically collapse views that have `isHidden` set to true. I think that as long as the direct subviews of the `StackView` have an intrinsic content size (e.g. correct internal constraints), they should be placed correctly by the `StackView`.

Comment: Thanks! I will give sackViews a go then!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the constant of the heightAnchor constraint like so:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TestController : UIViewController {

var myViewHeightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

let myView : UIControl = {
    let newView = UIControl()
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newView.backgroundColor = .red
    return newView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white


    self.myView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(viewClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.myViewHeightConstraint = myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.heightAnchor)

    setup()
}

func setup(){

    view.addSubview(myView)

    myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    self.myViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true

}

@objc func viewClicked() {
    self.myViewHeightConstraint.constant = -self.myView.frame.size.height
}
```

}

In my example, I set the constant to minus the height of the view's frame height, which effectively collapses it.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a solution, but I have a looot of views with nested views. Would a cleaner solution be to make those UI elements into their separate classes with their own subviews  and set their constraints as properties on the specific instance of that class?

Comment: @ArneOldenhave I'm not really sure what your view looks like. If you could maybe sketch out something it might help. From what I gather from your comment is that you have a lot of views that are different which contain a lot of subviews? If that's the case then it'd probably be cleaner to subclass UIView and set all that stuff up in there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update my question with a few screesnhots